# validateDebugSigning ERROR , Telegram Messanger (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, telegram

I have imported a new project into my android studio workspace and it was no problem to importing it. When i tried to build it , i got an error which is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:validateDebugSigning'.
> Keystore file /Users/prasenjeetpati/Downloads/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/config/release.keystore not found for signing config 'debug'.
```

I build project in android studio,and i run it on my mac .The project which i  was importing was [this](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) .

***Update***

I just saw that the project which is in github is lower version then that is play store. so i think the bug free code has not been updated to github.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: not found yet . still searching .

Comment: What the hell is wrong with telegram. I tried with iOS and Android projects from git but both did not build, very buggy projects on git